# Rails Console is not querying the table in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, irb, ruby-on-rails-6

Altruists,
I am new in Rails, I have a devise user model named **Account**. I have signed up with my email, and I want to query my Account table from rails console, like I did in Rails 5 without any problem.
It's noteworthy that, I am using Rails 6 in **Windows 10 with Ubuntu Subsystem**.

[Please see the picture of my Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg7Mg.png)

in line 002 there is no output. I am facing the same problem for all model. It does not query anything even though the model contains data.
Please help me.

Comment: out of curiosity, have you tried `spring stop`?

Comment: And including some source code might help.  You might also try starting a new project in rails 6 and see if you get the same behavior.